# how to use tf and idf in rescore of elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tf-idf

I'm new to `elasticseasrch`. I use `elasticsearch` in my project and want to use `tf` and `idf` for rescoring the result of `elasticsearch`. But I don't know if `elasticsearch` gives me the `tf` or `idf` of each term in query.

```
  {
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my_field": "my text"
    }
  },
  "rescore": {
    "window_size": 100,
    "query": {
      "rescore_query": {
        "script_score": {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "my_field": "my text"
            }
          },
          "script": {
            "source": " sum(tf(term)*idf(term)),
          }
        }
      },
      "query_weight": 0,
      "rescore_query_weight": 1
     }
  }
}
```

for example I want to implement this formula in rescore function. what should I do?